# using skimage shannon-entropy to calculate image entropy

Tags: entropy, image-processing, scipy

I'm using shannon-entropy function in skimage to calculate entropy of grey-scale image.
After examine the its source code:

```
def shannon_entropy(image, base=2):
    return scipy_entropy(image.ravel(), base=base)
```

where scipy_entropy is :

```
def scipy_entropy(pk, qk=None, base=None):
    pk = asarray(pk)
    pk = 1.0*pk / np.sum(pk, axis=0)
    if qk is None:
        vec = entr(pk)
    else:
        qk = asarray(qk)
        if len(qk) != len(pk):
            raise ValueError("qk and pk must have same length.")
        qk = 1.0*qk / np.sum(qk, axis=0)
        vec = rel_entr(pk, qk)
    S = np.sum(vec, axis=0)
    if base is not None:
        S /= log(base)
    return S
```

we can see that scipy_entropy receive pk as a sequence of probability. However, the img.ravel() only give the flatten array of image.

I suppose it should do sth. like img.hist() to get the frequency distribution of different grey-scale value. 
Can any one explain what does it mean? Of maybe I have some misunderstand of entropy calculation?

Comment: It's unclear what you are looking for.  Would you be asking why the entropy depends only on the frequencies of values of the image and not on their locations?

Comment: for example, a 2x2 img [[100,100],[101,102]], to calculate the entropy, we first count the frequency of grey scale value.    100: 2,  101: 1, 102:1    then we get a prob. vector(0.5,0.25,0.25) then we use this to calculate the entropy.    but in skimage shannon_entropy function, it just flatten the image to flatten_img = [100,100,101,102] and  treat flatten_img/flatten_img.sum() as a prob. vector, which is wried